# input com jquery envia valor, mas php não consulta no BD alguma sujestão?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, input

```
    <script>
 jQuery(function($){                
                $('#busca-cid').submit(function(){                    
                    $.post('lista-cidades.php', $('#busca-cid input'), function(retorna){                        
                       
                        $("#cidades-atendidas").html(retorna);
                        
                    });
                    
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>

 pagina php:

$buscar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'busca', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//$buscar = 'ca';
$paginas = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pagi', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$qntd_result_pg = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qntd_pg', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
//calcular o inicio visualização


$ini = ($paginas * $qntd_result_pg) - $qntd_result_pg;

//consultar no banco de dados


 $result_cid = "SELECT cdstr_cidades.id, cdstr_cidades.cidade, cdstr_cidades.estado, cdstr_cidades.telefone, cdstr_cidades.dt_cadastro, cdstr_terminais.cid_term FROM cdstr_cidades INNER JOIN cdstr_terminais ON cdstr_cidades.id_terminal = cdstr_terminais.id WHERE cdstr_cidades.cidade LIKE '$buscar%' LIMIT $ini, $qntd_result_pg";
    $resultado_cid = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cid);

var_dump($buscar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que parece você está passando o elemento da DOM como parâmetro do post, e não o valor dele em si, que é o que queremos.

Passe ele na função com um objeto, para ter certeza de que esse valor será o mesmo no backend:

```
$.post(
     'lista-cidades.php', 
     { busca: $('#busca-cid input').val() },
     function(retorna){
         $("#cidades-atendidas").html(retorna);
     }
)
```

Assim, você terá certeza que o elemento será o mesmo que está tentando recuperar no PHP.

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, o erro deve estar no modo que você está referenciando esse elemento pelo javascript. Tente:

```
console.log( $('#busca-cid input').val() )
```

Assim, terá certeza que está pegando o valor que quer e enviando ele sem ser null ou undefined na sua requisição.

Espero ter ajudado!!